# Mounting /var/www for File recovery

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, ubuntu-12.04, chroot

I'm in the process of recovering my server's files in a "Rescue" mode. Its a Ubuntu 12.04 with 2x3TB in RAID1. The instructions were to SSH into the server in "Rescue" mode, mount the partitions, chroot into `/mnt` and recover my files. I also have to change my root password after `chroot`ing.

**Problem:** I cant seem to mount the partition for `/var/www` which is where most of my files are at.

When I tried mounting `/` and `/var/www`

```
root@rescue:~# mount /dev/md3 /mnt/

mount: /dev/md3 already mounted or /mnt/ busy
mount: according to mtab, /dev/md3 is already mounted on /mnt

root@rescue:~# /dev/sda /mnt/var/www

mount: /dev/sda already mounted or /mnt/var/www busy
```

However after `chroot` I see nothing inside `/var/www`!!! Did i mount wrongly or lost all my data?

```
root@rescue:~# chroot /mnt/

root@rescue:/# ls /var/www
root@rescue:/#
```

**Parition Wizard setup**

[image]

**fdisks -l**

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 364801 cylinders, total 5860533168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 3000.6 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 364801 cylinders, total 5860533168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/md3: 21.5 GB, 21473722368 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 5242608 cylinders, total 41940864 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Alignment offset: 3584 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md3 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/md2: 314 MB, 314507264 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 76784 cylinders, total 614272 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Alignment offset: 3584 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md2 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Comment: What is the output of `df`?

Comment: Add also the contents of `/mnt/etc/fstab`. I strongly doubt `/dev/sda` should be mounted at `/var/www`.

Comment: What partition are the files on that you are trying to recover?